# React developer tools showing "This page is using the development build of React" even after running npm run build

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app, production

I am fairly new to react. I made an app in react and before hosting I created the build files by running `npm run build`. It successfully created a build folder with files. I served the build using the command serve -s build and I navigated to localhost:3000. The app loads without any problem. But when I checked the react developer tools, it is showing that the app is in development build.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.1.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.52.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@zegocloud/zego-uikit-prebuilt": "^1.8.2",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.6",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to console.log the `process.env.NODE_ENV` in the production build and it logs production to the console in the production build.
I tried clearing browser cache, tried running the app in a new browser and even tried running it in an entirely different PC. The result is the same.